# Sending utf8 string using json from android to php

Tags: php, android, json

I am using below method to send data from android app to php script:

```
    JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("name", "name ąęś");
        jsonObject.put("address", "address żżóóó");
        jsonObject.put("title", "title ćććżżżóóó");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }zamiast



    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    String url = "http://www.serwer.com/script.php";

    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("post", jsonObject.toString()));
    // getting JSON Object
    // Note that create product url accepts POST method
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", params);
```

In php script site I receive data like that:

```
if(isset($_POST['post']))
{
    $post_utf8 = htmlentities($_POST['post'],ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $postX = htmlspecialchars_decode($post_utf8);

    $post_x = json_decode($postX, true);

    echo $_POST['post']; //--> problem with utf8 , "?" instead polish characters
    echo $post_x['name']; //--> problem with utf8 , "?" instead polish characters
    echo "ąęź"; // --> everything OK, I can see polish characters
}
```

I can always see "?" instead of polish characters.
Using echo "ąźć" I can see polish characters.
Meening of this is that is something wrong with POST method.
I already checked many things but unfortunately I didn't find solution till now.

Answer (score 0):

When doing an AJAX request with UTF-8 to a PHP Server application you have to make sure that 1) frontend supports UTF8 (when submitting a form e.g. HTML encoding must be set to UTF8), 2) Webserver is configured to use UTF-8 (Apache: AddDefaultCharset utf-8), 3) PHP is configured to use UTF8.

Comment: It can be little bit difficult. I use web hosting. I don't have access to php / apache configuration files. This is popular Polish hosting: home.pl . It is strange if they not use utf 8 in default because it is Polish hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Java Strings use Unicode and the JSON Strings are UTF-8 encoded. Thats why firstly we need to change Unicode String to UTF8 String like below:

```
JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject();
try {
    jsonObject.put("name", "name ąęś");
    jsonObject.put("address", "address żżóóó");
    jsonObject.put("title", "title ćććżżżóóó");

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}zamiast



JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
String url = "http://www.serwer.com/script.php";


String utf8String = "";
try {
    utf8String = new String(jsonObject.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}





// Building Parameters
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("post", utf8String));
// getting JSON Object
// Note that create product url accepts POST method
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", params);
```